# Share data between mod_python processes

Tags: python, apache, mod-python, share

I'm running mod_python under Apache. If I've understood correctly, each Apache process runs its own Python interpreter.

What would be the best way to share a tiny amount of data across all the processes? I'm talking about just a few hundred bytes here, making something database based completely overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in [shared memory](http://semanchuk.com/philip/sysv_ipc/).

Comment: Actually the author of sysv_ipc seems to recommend using posix_ipc instead.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is to use file IO.  One process writes the file and the other reads it.  You can use the [`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html#module-mmap) module to make this a little more seamless.  One interesting alternative that I haven't tried (yet) is to use some derivative of [`multiprocessing.Manager`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.managers) to communicate between the processes.  I haven't tried the latter, I was looking for some way to create a process-shared semaphore.